# Specific where for multiple selects

Tags: sql, select

I have the following problem:

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
ArticleID|Group|Price
1|a|10
2|b|2
3|a|3
4|b|5
5|c|5
6|f|7
7|c|8
8|x|3
```

Now im trying to get a result like this:

```
PriceA|PriceRest
13|30
```

Meaning I want to sum all prices from group a in one column and the sum of everything else in another column.

Something like this doesnt work.

```
select 
    sum(Price) as PriceGroupA
    sum(Price) as PriceRest
from
    Table
where
    Group='a'
    Group<>'a'
```

Is there a way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
sum(case when [Group] = 'a' then Price else 0 end) as PriceA,
sum(case when [Group] <> 'a' then Price else 0 end) as PriceRest
from
Table
```

Comment: Does not show only a single group with two columns.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select
    sum(case when [Group]='A' then Price end) PriceA,
    sum(case when [Group]<>'A' then Price end) PriceRest
from
    Table
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/94c7c/15)

Comment: Does not show only a single group with two columns.

Answer (score 0):

You just need two sub-queries:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(PRICE)
        FROM Table1 
        WHERE [Group] ='a') AS PriceGroupA,
       (SELECT SUM(PRICE)
        FROM Table1 
        WHERE [Group]<>'a') AS PriceRest
```

[**Demo-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/94c7c/11/0)